# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable using Seleniumthrough Python in pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, firefox, webdriver, geckodriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.firefox("D:\Pycharm_automation\geckodriver-v0.27.0-win64\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get("google.com")
```

1. While executing, I'm facing type error. I'm not able to open firefox and chrome driver.
2. Already i have installed chrome and gecko drivers.

Comment: try replacing ```\``` with ```\\``` in the path.

Answer (score 0):

I have my "geckodriver.exe" right beside of my script.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

import time
opts = Options()   
browser = Firefox(options=opts)
browser.get("www.google.de")
```

Comment: Hi, Still issue happening...it's like "TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Comment: Could you post the traceback?

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

...implies that your code is trying to call the **firefox** module which is not callable.

`firefox` is a submodule within the `webdriver` module.

[image: firefox_module]

---

### Solution

Instead you need to call `Firefox()`. You need to replace `firefox` with **`Firefox`**. Effectively, your code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'D:\Pycharm_automation\geckodriver-v0.27.0-win64\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("google.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

We begin by loading modules for Selenium webdriver and firefox.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
    service = Service() #Then we initialize service to default 
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)
    
    driver.get("http://www.python.org")
   
    driver.close()  # close - closes current FOCUSSED window
    driver.quit()  # quit- quits entire session
```

If you are using Selenium version 4.0 above, not required to setup the browser path and all.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).